# Where to use exception handling in calculator?

Tags: c#, exception

I have created calculator. It runs finally but once I start entering anything which is improper it throws a `FormatException`. I am attaching my code below, please suggest me how to handle exceptions in my program.

MyCalculator.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyCalculator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        float number, answer;
        int count;

        public void disable() //create new method to disable calculator
        {
            //follow are disable when call we disable() function
            Display.Enabled = false;
            On.Show();//it will be still display
            offbutton.Hide(); //it will be hide
            back.Enabled = false;
            clear.Enabled = false;
            Add.Enabled = false;
            Sub.Enabled = false;
            Multiply.Enabled = false;
            Divide.Enabled = false;
            Zero.Enabled = false;
            One.Enabled = false;
            Two.Enabled = false;
            Three.Enabled = false;
            Four.Enabled = false;
            Five.Enabled = false;
            Six.Enabled = false;
            Seven.Enabled = false;
            Eight.Enabled = false;
            Nine.Enabled = false;
            equal.Enabled = false;
            Point.Enabled = false;
        }

        public void enable() //create new method to enable calculator
        {
            //follow are enable we call enable() function
            Display.Enabled = true;
            On.Hide();//it will be hide
            offbutton.Show();//it will be still display 
            back.Enabled = true;
            clear.Enabled = true;
            Add.Enabled = true;
            Sub.Enabled = true;
            Multiply.Enabled = true;
            Divide.Enabled = true;
            Zero.Enabled = true;
            One.Enabled = true;
            Two.Enabled = true;
            Three.Enabled = true;
            Four.Enabled = true;
            Five.Enabled = true;
            Six.Enabled = true;
            Seven.Enabled = true;
            Eight.Enabled = true;
            Nine.Enabled = true;
            equal.Enabled = true;
            Point.Enabled = true;
        }
        private void Point_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         //Display dot(.) in textbox when press dot(.) button with red color
            Display.Text = Display.Text+".";
            Display.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }

        private void Zero_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
       //Display zero(0) in textbox when press zero(0) button with red color
            Display.Text = Display.Text + 0;
            Display.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }

        private void One_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Display 1 in textboc when press 1 button with red color
            Display.Text = Display.Text + 1;
            Display.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }

        private void Two_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Display 2 in textboc when press 2 button with red color
            Display.Text = Display.Text + 2;
            Display.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }

        private void Three_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Display 3 in textboc when press 3 button with red color
            Display.Text = Display.Text + 3;
            Display.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }

        private void Four_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Display 4 in textboc when press 4 button with red color
            Display.Text = Display.Text + 4;
            Display.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }

        private void Five_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Display 5 in textboc when press 5 button with red color
            Display.Text = Display.Text + 5;
            Display.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }

        private void Six_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Display 6 in textboc when press 6 button with red color
            Display.Text = Display.Text + 6;
            Display.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }

        private void Seven_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Display 7 in textboc when press 7 button with red color
            Display.Text = Display.Text + 7;
            Display.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }

        private void Eight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Display 8 in textboc when press 8 button with red color
            Display.Text = Display.Text + 8;
            Display.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }

        private void Nine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Display 9 in textboc when press 9 button with red color
            Display.Text = Display.Text + 9;
            Display.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }

        private void offbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//off button
        {
            disable(); //call disable to off calculator
        }

        private void On_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //on button
        {
            enable(); //call enable function to on calculator
        }

        public void compute()
        {

            switch (count) //creating switch statement
            {
                 case 1:
                 answer = number + float.Parse(Display.Text);
                 //it performs addition

                 Display.Text = answer.ToString();              
                 //converts float into string
                 break;
                 case 2:
                     answer = number - float.Parse(Display.Text); 
//it performs subtraction
                     Display.Text = answer.ToString();              //converts float into string
                     break;
                 case 3:
                     answer = number * float.Parse(Display.Text);   //it performs Multiplication
                     Display.Text = answer.ToString();              //converts float into string
                     break;
                  case 4:
                      answer = number / float.Parse(Display.Text);   //it performs Division
                      Display.Text = answer.ToString();              //converts float into string
                      break;
                   default:
                      break;
                }

        }

        private void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            number = float.Parse(Display.Text);
            Display.Clear(); //clear the textbox
            Display.Focus(); //focus on textbox after clear
            count = 1; //count store case
            label1.Text = number.ToString() + "+"; //display text on lable
        }

        private void Sub_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            number = float.Parse(Display.Text);
            Display.Clear(); //clear the textbox
            Display.Focus(); //focus on textbox after clear
            count = 2; //count store switch case value
            label1.Text = number.ToString() + "-"; //display text on lable

        }

        private void Multiply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            number = float.Parse(Display.Text);
            Display.Clear(); //clear the textbox
            Display.Focus(); //focus on textbox after clear
            count = 3; //count store switch case value
            label1.Text = number.ToString() + "*"; //display text on lable
        }

        private void Divide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            number = float.Parse(Display.Text);
            Display.Clear(); //clear the textbox
            Display.Focus(); //focus on textbox after clear
            count = 4; //count store switch case value
            label1.Text = number.ToString() + "/"; //display text on lable
        }

        private void equal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            compute();//call compute function to perform such operations
            label1.Text = "";//clear the text on the lable
        }

        private void clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//clear button
        {
            Display.Text = ""; //clear the textbox
        }

        private void back_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//backspace button
        {
            int length = Display.TextLength - 1;
            string text = Display.Text;
            Display.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                Display.Text = Display.Text + text[i];

        }


    }
}
```

please help me out as soon as possible

Comment: _it runs finely but once i started entering anything which is improper it throws a format exception_ so it doesnt run finely! ;)

Comment: `where do i use exception handling` - around the statement that causes exceptions, which is `float.Parse` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

How about using

```
if(!float.TryParse(Display.Text, out number))
    return;

//rest of your code
```

Comment: @interceptwind In fact this is no real answer to the question. "please suggest me how to handle exceptions" - handle them not prevent them :P

Comment: @FeDe Answering to the X part of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640) is fine, and is arguably better than answering to the Y part.

Answer (score -1):

Use  `Try {} catch {}` !

Basically you can use it everywhere. I suggest using it always when you do some logik to make your program as stable as possible. The main task it to do the error handling nice(stronly recommended). So when using TryCatch (example shown below) do something in the catch block. Show a MessageBox displaying a selfmade errorMessage or showing the ex.Message to the user.

In your case I would implement it for:

1. Any Method containing a cast/parse -> InvalidCastException is catched
2. Any Method doing math operations

For example:

```
try
{
   //Do your logic here !
}
catch(Exception ex) //Here you can catch any type of Exception 
{                   //like InvalidFormatException, and even print out ex.Message
   //Do something
   //Logging, MessageBox(Invalid operation ..), ...
}
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/0yd65esw.aspx  and

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms229005%28v=vs.100%29.aspx for more infos.